# Changing the text of button dynamically contaning span class

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing a problem where I have a button in which I am changing the text of it based on the click.
This `button` has a `span` attached to it.
But when I change the value of `innerHTML/innerText` of the `button`, the `span` gets removed and the picture thats supposed to come with the `button` does not appear.
I have tried adding `"className"` and `'classList.add("text")'`, but its just throwing an error.
So I wanted to know if there is any way I could only change the text of the `button` without effecting the `button's` `span` element.

Thank you in advance :)

This is how the button is declared

```
<button id='btnShow' class='btn btn-info pull-right' onclick='pingall()'><i class='fa fa-desktop'></i>Show All</button>
```

I'm using javascript and changing the value of text by

```
var showallButton=document.getElementById('btnShow');
if((showallButton.innerText).trim()=="Show All"){        
    showallButton.innerHTML="Hide All";
}else{
    showallButton.innerHTML="Show All";         
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `textNode` after the `i` tag and update its content.

```js
function pingall(){
  // get the i tag within button then get the text content
  // after the tag using nextSibling property
  var textNode = document.querySelector('#btnShow i').nextSibling;

  // check textContetnt property for updating or checking
  if ((textNode.textContent).trim() == "Show All") {
    textNode.textContent = "Hide All";
  } else {
    textNode.textContent = "Show All";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id='btnShow' class='btn btn-info pull-right' onclick='pingall()'><i class='fa fa-desktop'></i>Show All</button>
```

Comment: hey @pranav ,thank you so much .This works beautifully :)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have an icon element within the button.

You can update the HTML to:

```
<button id='btnShow' class='btn btn-info pull-right' onclick='pingall()'><i class='fa fa-desktop'></i><span id="btn-text">Show All</span></button>
```

And the JS to:

```
var showallButtonText=document.getElementById('btn-text');
if((showallButtonText.innerText).trim()=="Show All"){        
    showallButtonText.innerHTML="Hide All";
}else{
    showallButtonText.innerHTML="Show All";         
}
```

Comment: Thank you @emily :) but pranav's suggestions makes more sense for the way I have the DOM. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

`INNERHTML` replaces all content inside an HTML element.
So in your case it removes all content including `<span>` tags and it adds "Hide All" or "Show All".
To only replace the text you can use the `ID` of your `<span>` element.

```
var textNode = document.querySelector('#idofyourspan');
```

You can also get the next element after your `<i>` with `nextSibling`

```
var textNode = document.querySelector('#btnShow i').nextSibling; // this should be your <span>
```

Full code:

```js
var textNode = document.querySelector('#btnShow i').nextSibling; // get the next sibling after <i> tag inside button

// check textContetnt property for updating or checking
if ((textNode.textContent).trim() == "Show All") {
  textNode.textContent = "Hide All";
} else {
  textNode.textConten = "Show All";
}
function pingall(){
// your code

}
```

```html
<button id='btnShow' class='btn btn-info pull-right' onclick='pingall()'><i class='fa fa-desktop'></i>Show All</button>
```